# How does "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" work in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to understand the syntax of `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in Cassandra.

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nonexistanttable;` does not seem to work:

```
$ ./cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.5 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> USE Foo;
cqlsh:foo> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bar;
Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily bar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` is that you avoid getting the InvalidRequestException "Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily" by droping the table only if it is actually created so your query statement is valid.

You are getting the exception because this was a [bug in 2.0.5.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6687) It has been fixed for C* 2.0.6 but if you want to see `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` immediately, try downloading and building cassandra from source:

```
git clone -b cassandra-2.0 git://git.apache.org/cassandra.git cassandra
cd cassandra
ant build
```